Moses at the mount speaking to the people
How did Moses speak to the people at the mountain when he was at the top and they were at the bottom. The mountain is 7500 feet high. This doesn't seem possible

This question needs to provide scriptural support for the claim it makes.

Continuing Ray's comment, where does it say in Exodus that he was at the top of the mountain when speaking to the people?  Which mountain is 7500 feet high?  We don't have sure evidence of any mountain today being Sinai, just some varied opinions on likely candidates.

Welcome to the group Bob C. Please find the chapter and verse you are wondering about and include this reference in your OP.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Moses was called up Mount Sinai several times. Each time he went up, he later came down, which was when he spoke to the Israelites, to convey what God had said to him.
Until specific verses are stated, the question cannot be answered hermeneutically, but the simple answer is, whichever occasion is in mind, Moses went up, and then he came down.
Some examples of this can be found in Exodus 19:14 & 20-21 & 24
Exodus 19:18-19
Exodus 32:1 & 7 & 15
Now, to keep this question open, one or two specific verses must be quoted, with the reference given, and then a hermeneutic examination of the verse/s may be undertaken. Please add (by editing in) such information to the question.

To add to what Anne posted, Exodus 19 defines what was meant by "the mountain."

And you shall set limits for the people all around, saying, ‘Take care
not to go up into the mountain or touch the edge of it. Whoever
touches the mountain shall be put to death. No hand shall touch him,
but he shall be stoned or shot; whether beast or man, he shall not
live.’ When the trumpet sounds a long blast, they shall come up to the
mountain.” - Exodus 19:12, 13 ESV

Thus, a mountain is not simply the peak, but includes the elevated approaches to it. Moses spoke to the people from an elevated location, not from the peak.
